# Linux monitoring - Nagios and nrpe

Tags: linux, networking, nagios

The communication between nagios and a nrpe agent installed in a monitored machined can be without SSL? My problem is that I have two different versions of linux and cant find compatible versions of libssl-dev to do that.

Comment: You don't need the same version of libssl-dev. The TLS protocol is standardized and newer and older libssls can talk to each other. Oh, and, Serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The check_nrpe plugin, which is used to call the command check on the remote host (defined in the nrpe.cfg file), supports the -n option: Do not use SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can install `check_nrpe` without using ssl. Look for the syntax below:

Get the latest version of `check_nrpe` and untar the package:

```
tar xzf check_nrpe-2.16.tar.gz
cd check_nrpe-2.16
./configure --without-ssl
```

this will install `check_nrpe` without ssl.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you don't need to have same version of ssl libraries for this. However, you would need same version of NRPE on both the server and the client which can surely be done.